# 3D animation is not rendered on libgdx GWT backend

Tags: html, animation, gwt, libgdx

I have created a 3D animation in Blender for my libgdx game and it works fine on android, desktop and iOS. However, when I try to port my game to GWT HTML5 backend, I could not see the animating model instance on the screen. I do not get any exception or error log, just an invisible animation.

Somehow it plays the animation in the background as it calls the AnimationListener.onEnd() method when animation is ended but it cannot render it on the screen.

Please note: all other static 3D model instances (created via Blender as well) are rendered fine on the screen and I'm using libgdx 1.4.1 with GWT 2.6

Is it a know issue with GWT backend? Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: never tested in libgdx html, but you have Web-GL enabled in your Browser. Or is it not proved necessary for that purpose?

Comment: Web-GL is enabled in my browser and it is working fine for other 3D model instances. The only problem seems to be related with animation model instance. It is not displayed on the screen.